# How to print the string value from cdktf data sources with python

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cdk

**Problem**

I am trying to retrieve the subnet cidr block range using CDKTF data_aws_subnet, but doing so gives me an output as `$TfTokenTOKEN` instead of an actual cidr range (example 10.42.0.0/24)

**Code**

```
import cdktf_cdktf_provider_aws.data_aws_subnet as DataAwssubnet_

self.data_subnet = DataAwssubnet_.DataAwsSubnet(
            self.scope_obj,self.id_, availability_zone = '$$-south-1a', vpc_id='vpc-0d$$$e$$$$2$$$$3')

print(self.data_subnet.cidr_block)
```

> above code outputs some weird encrypted value instead of a string

How can I print this value using data_aws_subnet module of CDKTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a [Token](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/tokens) there, to print the `cidr_block` you need to use a [`TerraformOutput`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/variables-and-outputs#output-values).

```
import cdktf_cdktf_provider_aws.data_aws_subnet as DataAwssubnet_
from cdktf import TerraformOutput

self.data_subnet = DataAwssubnet_.DataAwsSubnet(
        self.scope_obj,self.id_, availability_zone = '$$-south-1a', vpc_id='vpc-0d$$$e$$$$2$$$$3')

TerraformOutput(self, "subnet_cidr_block", value=self.data_subnet.cidr_block)
```

Comment: How can I store this in a python variable?

Comment: You can only store the token inside of a variable, the real value is not introspectable since the Terraform code is first synthesized by executing your program and then at a second step executed